# (mac) dockers , commit changes in mongo doesn't work

Tags: docker, boot2docker

new to dockers. running using `boot2docker` on a `mac`.

1. running a container with no data in it `docker run --name mongodb -p 27017:27017 -d mongo`.
2. importing data onto it `mongorestore --host 192.168.59.104 -d dest source` The import works and I see the data in the container.
3. committing (without pushing) the container to the image `docker commit mongdb mongo`
4. when stopping, removing and restarting , the data is not saved. `docker stop mongodb; docker rm mongdb; docker run --name mongodb -p 27017:27017 -d mongo`

Notes:
docker commit after the import doesn't show any diff in the data:

```
docker diff mongodb                                                                                              ✱
C /root
C /root/.bash_history
C /root/.dbshell
C /tmp
C /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is mongo's Dockerfile contains

```
VOLUME /data/db
```

Therefore, the data is not being stored in the image, but in boot2docker. One solution would be to build your own image using the mongo Dockerfile as a example, but exclude the VOLUME option.

Comment: this is the same across all docker hosts, including ubuntu. Another option is to track down where the volume has been mounted to and copy the data to where the volume for the other container. In docker 1.8 you can do this with docker inspect on the first container, find the Mounts property in the json it returns. Then do the same on the second docker container to find out where to copy the data to